# Apache: .htaccess file is read from the top drive directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory, httpd.conf

My DocumentRoot is `e:/www` - below my `httpd.conf` file part:

```
DocumentRoot "e:/www"
<Directory "e:/www">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Options +Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from ::1
    Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```

and I have 2 `.htaccess` files phisically located here:

1. e:/www/.htaccess
2. e:/.htaccess

There is no additional Alias created in `httpd.conf` file.

`e:/.htaccess` is read and its contents affect server perfomance.

Why are the contents read at all??

Comment: Repeat Question: [Block access to a web subdirectory with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333673/block-access-to-a-web-subdirectory-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to note. You should not use .htaccess if you have access to the main config file e.g. **httpd.conf**. It slows down your web server because Apache has to scan the directories for htaccess files and apply the rules. It is the preferred method to put it in the config in the `Directory` directive. Any time the config is modified, Apache must be reloaded/restarted also.

So because it has to scan all directories it will see the .htaccess file at the level up above which in your case is `e:\.htaccess`.

So if you request a file from e:\www\example. It will look for the .htaccess files in these directories

```
e:\.htaccess
e:\www\.htaccess
e:\www\example\.htaccess
```

That's why htaccess is not good for performance. It's mostly used for shared hosting or for times when you don't have direct access to the `httpd.conf` file.

Read this section on **[When not to use .htaccess files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)** from the Apache foundation.
It will clear up any questions about this.

Comment: this document explains everything here and still I need to use .htaccess file since I eventually put the project on the shared hosting server.